# Counting number of occurrences by particular stage

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a snapshot of a table running each night and am looking to get the total time a company stays in a particular stage.

i.e company A spent 2 days in 'Sales'. company B 2 days in 'Sales' and 1 day in 'Negotiation'.
I don't care about days in 'Closed' since at that time the opportunity would be won.

```
Name Stage Extract_Date
A    Sales 2020-07-04
A    Sales 2020-07-05
A    Closed 2020-07-06
B    Sales 2020-07-04
B    Sales 2020-07-05
B    Negot 2020-07-06
B    Closed 2020-07-07
B    Closed 2020-07-08
C    Sales 2020-07-04
C    Sales 2020-07-05
```

I'm at a complete block at starting this, would it as simple as

```
SELECT Name, Stage, COUNT(Extract_Date)
FROM Table
GROUP BY Name, Stage
```

Or would a window function be more approriate?

Comment: Just do count (distinct extract_date)

Comment: SELECT Name, COUNT(Extract_Date)
FROM NAMES where Stage!='Negot'
GROUP BY Name ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think you are close.  Assuming states do not repeat (as in your sample data):

```
select name, stage, min(extract_date) as start_date,
       lead(min(extract_date)) over (partition by name order by min(extract_date)) as end_date
from t
group by name, stage;
```

You can then use an appropriate function such as `datediff()` or `timestampdiff()` to get the difference you want.

Comment: that'll get me most of the way there I think and I can aggregate further. thanks!